# What are headers in REST Api?

Tags: rest

What is the purpose of having headers? 
Why it is compulsory to add headers in request body?

Sample Code:

```
HttpPost methodPut = new HttpPost(url);
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
methodPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there can be more than one  "Content-Type".

Comment: A "Content-type" is simply a header defined in HTTP and other protocol  to indicate in which format content is expected.

Comment: Thanks Prabir.. I had little confusion but now I got it..